# How to fix some png's that are rendered corrupted on Android using libgdx

Tags: android, libgdx

I am using libgdx and tween engine and Android.  Most of the png's are rendered to Texture and the Texture is passed to a Sprite which is then rendered on screen.

Many of the png's work ok, but some fail with the attached result

What could be causing this ?  How do I work around it ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are your PNG files "paletted"?  (See https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/issues/detail?id=895 and [the doc for Pixmap's constructor](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/Pixmap.html#Pixmap-com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle-).)  Its an old bug, but I think its still relevant to Libgdx.

You should be able to use some PNG tools (probably ImageMagick, at least) depending on your platform to find out what format these PNG files are in that may be causing a problem.

Comment: How do I check if they are paletted ?

Comment: I don't have a solution for this problem yet, but one workaround is to read the png and draw it on a Bitmap using Android canvas.  Saving that Bitmap canvas creates a file that renders correctly.